# Difference between MakeFile and Console App in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, console-application, difference

For class I need to make a GUI based project. I chose C++ in Visual Studio. Saw a video of a guy making a simple factorial calculator app in Visual Studio, but at the beginning he chose MakeFile instead of ConsoleApp, and I was taught to use ConsoleApp but never the difference. Should I use MakeFile or can I do it at ConsoleApp?

Comment: A MakeFile project allows you to link to external libraries.

Comment: Use the console app. Makefile is a text file (that you have to create and know how to create) that generates the project outside the IDE using a separate program called NMAKE which you run from a command prompt. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-a-makefile-project?view=msvc-160](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-a-makefile-project?view=msvc-160) If you don't know this it will be a lot of work to get it up and running.

Comment: The makefile, like a compilation rule for a project, helps you manually determine the order of compilation and linking. If you use Console app, IDE will automatically complete the build for you. By the way, about creating a GUI based project in vs, maybe you could create a [win 32 desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) or [MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?view=msvc-160)